# Transcribing Intellectual Thought

Tags: riddle

A device to strike a tone, you should think me not,

For I am a way to transcribe intellectual thought,

And though all that I contain has many a name,

Their ultimate function remains the same.

Who am I?

Hint:

> Though you all seem to have the right thought, parts of the first line will really *hammer* it home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a

> Keyboard.

A device to strike a tone, you should think me not,

> In addition to an input peripheral for PCs, the word "keyboard" can also refer to a musical instrument.

For I am a way to transcribe intellectual thought,

> The most common way to put thoughts into writing today is through a keyboard.

And though all that I contain has many a name,

> Each key on the keyboard has a distinct name.

Their ultimate function remains the same.

> A key's ultimate function is to input a character into your computer.

Comment: yup! that's the ticket

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> typewriter

A device to strike a tone, you should think me not,

> Each key makes a specific sound when striking the paper, such that [spies would place microphones inside typewriters](http://www.forbes.com/sites/bruceupbin/2015/04/20/new-browser-hack-can-spy-on-eight-out-of-ten-pcs/) to listen to what was typed.

For I am a way to transcribe intellectual thought,

> Typewriters let you transcribe your thoughts.

And though all that I contain has many a name,

> The keys all have different names depending on what letter they are.

Their ultimate function remains the same.

> Each key's function is to type out a letter.

Comment: this one is even closer though I think you have over thought the first line. Almost wanted to just give it to you but it really isn't the answer

Comment: I'm not going to say one way or another but if you think it fits...

Answer (score 0):

> You're a note.
>
> You're the device specifying what tone should be struck,
>  Intellectual thoughts are frequently jotted down to remember,
>  You can write any words you want in the note,
>  but words are ultimately always to communicate an idea.

Comment: Rather close. However, not quite on target. There are a few hints that don't _quite_ fit but I'm a fan of the answer none the less

Answer (score 0):

It must be:

> *drumroll* the vocal cords.

My thinking is thus:

A device to strike a tone, you should think me not,

> Your vocal cords can be thought of as being solely used to sing, but this is not the case!

For I am a way to transcribe intellectual thought,

> If we take "transcribe" to mean to translate, we have that your vocal cords "translate" your thoughts into words.

And though all that I contain has many a name,

> The various sounds made by a set of vocal cords fall under many names, these called 'onomatopoeia's, I believe.

Their ultimate function remains the same.

> The ultimate function is to convey your thoughts.

Comment: Very creative answer, though not correct.

Comment: @BrianCrawford Thank you! I'll keep thinking about the solution.